# Why does after move I can get sync to work but not after cp -r *?

Tags: linux, debian, coreutils

I have seen this happen multiple times. For example, I move a hypothetical file to a the usb disk.

```
$ mv somefilename.someext /media/shirish/Seagate/sometilename.someext
```

after this I simply say sync -

```
$ sync
```

If I do the same thing as copying it on the same hdd it would be -

```
$ cp -r somefolder /media/shirish/seagate/
```

Now if you try syncing, it goes into a sort of endless loop. Dos anybody know why ?

Update - 03/3/2016 - the data I am moving or copying is usually a media file about 300 MB in size so not much.

Comment: How much data are you copying / moving? Are the source and the target on the same filesystem (I assume not, but it's best confirmed)?

Comment: sync can be long if you have a very high memory and it is caching a lot of things, or if the drive being written to has a lot of pending opérations (can be very long in the case of some raid disks while they are rebuilding)